# nativescript-custom-local-notifications plugin gives: Cannot read property \'Builder\' of undefined Error

Tags: nativescript, android-notifications, localnotification

The **nativescript-custom-local-notifications** Plugin does not work for me ( but **nativescript-local-notifications** works ),

Here is the code:

```
import * as LocalNotifications from "nativescript-custom-local-notifications";

export default {
  methods: {
    onTapScheduleNotification () {
      LocalNotifications.schedule([{
        id: 1,
        title: 'The first title',
        body: 'The first  body',
        ticker: 'The ticker',
        badge: 1,
        sound: "sound1", //sound1 from /Appresources/raw/ folder
        at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (20 * 1000)) 
      }])
    }
  }
}
```

the result :

```
JS: 'Error in LocalNotifications.schedule: TypeError: Cannot read property \'Builder\' of undefined'
JS: 'scheduling error: TypeError: Cannot read property \'Builder\' of undefined'
```

I tried this:

```
tns platform remove android && tns run android
```

but still the problem persists.

Comment: Make sure you have installed latest support libraries from androidx repo.

Comment: my tns version is : `6.1.2` and  Android SDK Platform-Tools `revision: 29.0.5` , is that what you mean? or I need to install additional packages?

Comment: is that related to this? : `This constructor is deprecated.
use NotificationCompat.Builder(Context, String) instead. All posted Notifications must specify a NotificationChannel Id. ` since in `local-notifications.android.js` it uses : `var builder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(context)`